# Probability of event given evidence

Tags: probability

We have a stable with 4 empty spots for horses, A1, A2, A3, A4. We also have 5 horses of different sizes, H1 is size 5, H2 is also size 5, H3 is size 8 and H4 is size 9 and H5 is size 6.

We know that H5 has a 4/5 possibility of occupying a spot and H3 has a 1/5 possibility of occupying a spot.

We know that at a specific point in time, the time of the incident, H2 was occupying A1 and that the sum of the sizes of all stable spots is 23.

Furthermore, we assign a size of 5 to an unoccupied space, so say if A1 is occupied by H2, A2 is empty, A3 is empty and A4 is occupied by H3, then the overall size is 5+5+5+8=23.

The question is, what are the possible contents of the stable at the time of the incident?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $H_2$ is in $A_1$. I don't see any way to get $23$ using $H_4$ or $H_5$, but we need $H_3$ in one of the places. Then, $H_1$ is in one of the other two places, or not.

So, there are $9$ possibilities. $A_1$ always has $H_2$. $H_3$ is in one of the three remaining spots. For each of these, $H_1$ can be in either of the two remaining positions, or absent entirely.

(The probabilities in the second paragraph appear to be inconsequential to solving the problem.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Why are they inconsequential? 4/5 possibility of occupying the spot = the horse is in a stable spot 4/5 days a week. We don't know if at the time of the incident the horse is there or not...

Comment: Also, if I were to write this in mathematical notation, how would I go about it?

Comment: You asked for *possible* contents of the stable at the time of the incident. None are especially *likely* given the high probability assigned to $H_5$, but the sum of sizes restriction doesn't support using $H_5$. (There's no way to use exactly $3$ of $(5,5,5,8,9)$ to add up to $17$.) As for mathematical notation, you're just enumerating configurations, so pick a way that's clear.

Comment: If we know that there is only 9 possibilities of the sum being 23, how can we assign a probability to that? Is it enough by saying all the possible outcomes are n! so this possibility is 9/n!?

Comment: You didn't ask for probability; you asked for possible combinations.

Comment: Yes but I cannot just say I thought about it and it's 9 possibilities. When I say possible/probable contents I mean I need to express this in a mathematical way.

Comment: If you have other questions you need to work through, then I'm not sure what they are. If you are looking for probabilities, then you need to make assumptions, or you need more information. If you need just to state possibilities, then just reason it through like l did. There's nothing wrong with that. But I'm not understanding what you really need, sorry.